# laravel routing based on convention

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to setup a simple routing system based on convention.
My app will have this structure

```
Http
--Controllers
----Admin
------User.php
----Books
------Add.php
----etc...
```

I want to be able to add new Folders and controllers without adding routes manually to the web.php file.
For example I want the route to respond to /Admin/User URL with User.php controller.

I'm trying something like this, but I don't understand how to write the internal router...

```
Route::any('/{module}/{action?}', function($module, $action = 'index') {
    Route::get('*',$module.'\'.$action.'@index' );
});
```

It seems that Rout:get('*'... never matches.

PS the controller namespace is correct and I reloaded with composer. 
The controller works if called harcoded.

I tried also to escape '\'

```
$r=$module.'\\'.$action.'\\'.$action.'Ctl@index';
Route::get('/',$r );
```

But no result. The route is intercepted but nothing i served

Answer (score 0):

It seems I came up with this

```
Route::get('/{module}/{action}', function($module,$action) {

  return App::make('\App\Http\Controllers\\'
                   .$module.'\\'.$action)->callAction('index', []);

  });
```

Any other better way?

Comment: Please notice that this kind of practise will be tricky to handle and really hard to maintain. You should write your routes with hard coded controllers.

Comment: @Ole, that's the kind of comment I wanted to hear, but WHY it is so? From my point of view, I save time and maintenance, I don't have to touch routes anymore!

Comment: Because you have to generate your URLs in your views by looking up your source code structure and you have to change all your URLs, when you are changing your source code for whatever reasons.

Comment: @Ole, hmmm I don't understand really what you mean. I'm looking for a structure "convention based" in which all controllers are in /module-name/controllername and I don't want to add manually routes if I want a new URL path